# Speed difference between isscalar(x) and numel(x)==1

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, matrix

I was wondering what the speed difference is between the [`isscalar`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isscalar.html) and [`numel`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html) commands. I used this line of code to determine the time it takes for `isscalar` to determine if a given numeric array is scalar. I'm on MATLAB R2014b.

For `isscalar`:

```
tic, for x = 1:1e7, isscalar(x); end, toc
```

and for `numel`:

```
tic, for x = 1:1e7, numel(x)==1; end, toc
```

On my machine (i3 3220 or 3220T CPU) the code above takes about 0.3 seconds, so unless you have some very old machine, it will not take too much time. Be sure to run the code a few times before looking at the numbers: the first time you call a command like `tic` MATLAB loads it into memory, thus it takes longer than the actual code we're timing if it needs to load it first.

The result is in favor of `isscalar(x)`, which takes less than 0.3 seconds and the `numel(x)==1` about 0.33 seconds. This is probably significant (no statistics done here), because of the large number of repetitions (10^7).

However, when we change `x` to something different, e.g. `magic(3)` (which is a 3×3 matrix), the calculation takes much longer (I actually reduced the number of iterations down to 10^4). I did:

```
x = magic(3);
tic, for n = 1:1e7, isscalar(x); end, toc
```

takes about 0.3 seconds and

```
tic, for n = 1:1e7, numel(x)==1; end, toc
```

takes about 0.34 seconds.

This time the difference is about the same.

Why does this difference exist? I think it's logical `numel` takes a little longer because the logical test `==1` is done. How do `isscalar` and `numel` work? I think their algorithm might work as follows: get dimensions of input, then (for `isscalar`) determine whether any dimension is not equal to 1 (and return false, true otherwise) or (for `numel`) multiply the dimensions to get the number of elements.

Do you know about other examples of speed differences with `isscalar` and `numel`? And does this result differ on other CPUs (post your CPU and results as a comment if you like).

Note: the code inside `isscalar.m` and `numel.m` is either protected in [p-files](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcode.html) or contained in [MEX files](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html), so we cannot look at their source algorithms.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken these read out the array size from the low-level stack not with any high level matlab construct.

Comment: Now the benchmark is correct, but I am no longer able to reproduce your results. I don't get higher numbers using a matrix.

Comment: Why do you care about 0.04 seconds difference over 10 million iterations?